# Height-map low resolution displacement

Tags: height-map, resolution

Hi I am trying to import a height-map and create a 3d model of it, but when I import it the resolution of it is very low. I've seen it done in youtube videos and it seems I am doing the exact same, but their image imports at a much higher resolution and therefore they get much more detail in their model. My heightmap is 2017x2017 pixels. Anyone knows why this is happening?

I am very new to blender. I added a plane, a subdivision surface and a displace modifier

[image]

Comment: I am very new to blender fyi but I added a plane, a subdivision surface and a displace modifier https://ibb.co/bK9xXsc

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: You need many more vertices in the mesh you want to displace. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry/42641#42641

Comment: Also be very careful when using large values for the subsurf modifier. Read: [Blender render crash when using subsurf modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more vertices in the original plane.

The number of subdivisions in the mesh will be directly proportional with the level of detail for your displacement.

Comment: Thank you that worked :)