# Large Landscapes (A.N.T.) Performance?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, add-on

[image]

I've been trying to use the A.N.T. Landscape addon to design some large landscapes for Unreal Engine 4.

The problem is when I try to use large subdivision counts to visualize the details (Because I'm outputting them as heightmaps), I have to wait long periods of time when I make an update.  I know you can disable auto-refresh which I have done.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can increase performance when it comes to re-calculating the terrain in the editor?

Any insight would be appreciated.

[P.S.] I'm working this on a pretty nice gaming laptop with a 1050ti and 16GB of RAM.

Comment: There is no solution to this, other than buying a super-super fast computer. Subdivisions take up memory and they need processing power to work. No magic button, no hidden secret setting can do that. You could certainly use less subdivisions while editing and then create the final mesh in the end. Although that's still debatable, how a highly subdivided mesh is going to run on a RT game engine...

Comment: Nine million faces... you need a lot of RAM, plenty of processing power, and lots and lots of patience. Try optimizing your mesh as much as possible, use less subdivision and see if the decimate modifier can yield better topology.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry/42641#42641