# How to correct heightmap weird mesh effect on render in blender 2.8

Tags: height-map

Im relatively new in blender and Im trying to create a mesh from a heightmap (grey scale image of 16 bits) in blender (2.8), and everything appears to be fine but there is a lot of places when i see some weird effect over the surface:

[image: weir surface effects]
[image: Solid mesh]

here is the same generated mesh but in wireframe mode

[image]

the image i have used is 4096 x 4096 resolution and the mesh has aproximately 4 million verts (i think that this is not a resolution problem on the mesh).

What can i do to fix this problem. Im stucked with this.

Some other useful information:

- i have used the "smooth corrective" modifier, but it still looking like in the pictures.
- Im using the displacement modifier to build the mesh and this is the settings for the texture:

[image: texture settings (in displacement modifier)]
[image: texture settings (in displacement modifier)]

- this is the modifiers settings:

[image: modifiers setting]

- this was the "subdivision modifier" settings before apply it:

[image]

- all the normals are pointing to the right direction
- i have tried enabling/disabling backface culling.
- i have the subdivision modifier before the displacement modifier.

after adding an extra subsurf before displacement (thanks @susu), i getting this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry/42641#42641

Comment: i have the subdivision modifier before the displacement modifier. That is not the problem. thanks

Comment: Maybe you should read the link again. While a subsurf modifier will create more geometry for accurate displacement, a second subsurf after the displacement will make it smoother. Just watch out for the number of vertices not to climb to an unusable amount. The major problem you are going to face is that regular spacing in a complex mesh like this is not helpful, as you need more vertices in highly detailed areas and less in flatter parts. The decimate modifier or other re-topologizing tools can help you get the detail you need in a more optimized mesh.

Comment: It might be caused by non-planar faces on the lip of the edge where some quads have to "bend backwards" over themselves to accommodate the curve. Try select all > mesh > clean up > split non-planar faces

Comment: Also, for height maps you shouldn't use sRGB as the color space. It should be non-color, to avoid distortions caused by adding a gamma curve to the image.

Comment: @susu i have tried what you said, but im still getting the same issue

Comment: @ChristopherBennett i have tried to split non planar faces, but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: @susu i changed the sRGB to non-color, thanks for thath, Even though it improved the mesh,  the issue stills there

Comment: i have updated the post adding a new image to show you how it looks now, after the extra subsurf modifier added