# PC "not responding" when I use the Subsurf and Bevel modifier at the same time

Tags: modifiers

Blender "not responding" when I use the Subsurf and Bevel modifier at the same time. That is the only time Blender does this.  Anybody an idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Large amounts of calculations (very high polycounts) most likely

Comment: What level of subsurface and home many faces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender can become unresponsive if

- the combination of modifiers creates a **large amount of Faces**

Make sure the subsurf is turned to a low level when applying the bevel modifier!
Also keep in mind that changing the order of modifiers affects the order in which blender processes them.

- placing the subsurf as the second modifier **includes the bevel in the calculation**

If neither of the above causes the problem, try a different version of blender or a new file.

Comment: to get an idea of how many faces/vertices you are creating when using subsurf see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/how-do-i-know-the-number-of-polygons-after-adding-a-subdivision-surface-modifier/15667#15667