# Putting the texture on the object / Displace Modifier

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers

I created a plane, using normal map/displacement/occlusion/spec/diffuse and an blender displace modifier I made structure of the pavement. I would like to "put it" to the prepared system of roads. Unfortunately the disintegration of verticles on it is uneven and modifier works stronger in some places. By UV/Image editor I can fit the texture to the shape of the object, but how to make the modifier also followed this uv map? It is possible with this road model, or I have to create it on the other way? I don't have other ideas how to create a square...

As second, is it possible somehow to modify the texture so that roads would branch from the square and weren't just directed up?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Update: after modifications.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On top view UV select all of the faces  of your road object and do **unwrap form view**, so that the mapping is even and has the same scale.

Another thing worth trying is not using UVs for mapping on the modifier but an Empty.

Re-sizing and moving the empty might give you more control on the placement of the texture.

[image]

To make the displace modifier work smoother you might need to add a subsurf modifier before the displace modifier.

If you are not going to see the pavement texture very close on your image, you might want to consider using it as a bump map, instead of a real 3D displacement, that would require much denser geometry.

Comment: The camera will be on the level of the pavement. I forgot to write earlier: before using displace I applied the subdivide modifier and unwrap from view.  I also "manually" applied the subdivide on the biggest flat elements of the square aligning the grid a little bit what considerably improved the effect, but it is still is "stretched" in this place. Now I did it again and indeed the effect of spreading the modifier is such as he belongs, I had to miss something. Problem from sub surface is that, at value 2 it is diametrically increasing the number of verts - from 265 thousand to 5.3 million.

Comment: Apart from that after putting materials on road system (nodes are identical), in the solid view it looks like blender don't take them into consideration, however at material view is looks similarly to the sample... I am attaching two more picture.

Comment: Do be careful with the subsurf modifier! read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15667/1853

Comment: Create detailed geometry only in the parts of the model that will be displayed prominently. Areas that don't need dense geometry fake the relief with bump mapping. Another thing to try is to create the displacement, apply the modifier, and then decimate your mesh. So you keep the deformation but with less vertices.