# Generating vertex displacement accurately

Tags: sculpting

I am modeling an old building with walls of big, roughly cut stones, and I wonder if I could use a raster image of a wall to sculpt vertex displacement on a Blender object representing the wall by projecting the raster image onto the object, rather than applying it with a brush. The projection that controls vertex displacement needs to be accurate because I intend to use the same raster image to assign the materials of the stones and the mortar onto the wall object.

I've tried using the Displace modifier for this, and it appears to only use tileable textures, with no option for controlling the scale of the image projection. Can you do the same kind of work with UV maps that is done when assigning materials to generate vertex displacement on an object?

Comment: In the Displacement modifier there is a Texture Coordinate filed where you can pick UV. Did you tried it?

Comment: Yep, sounds like the *Displace* modifier is what you are looking for, all you need is to specify the correct UV coordinates, and properly unwrap your mesh.

Comment: you can control the size and placement of the texture for the displace modifier by using an empty. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46755/putting-the-texture-on-the-object-displace-modifier/46757#46757