# Computer is laggy when editing with Multiresolution

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution

After sculpting my mesh with Multiresolution modifier it became incredibly laggy. I can't even start render because of this although my PC isn't so bad. How do you make it work? [image]

Comment: unfortunately the image doesn't show the top of the window, where you can see the number of vertices and faces.

Comment: 9 300 000 vertices and same amount of faces, am i suppose to reduce them?

Comment: 9 million vertices is a lot... do you really need that many? To make the interface more responsive bring down the number of subdivisions for preview on the multires and subsurf. Read this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/how-do-i-know-the-number-of-polygons-after-adding-a-subdivision-surface-modifier/15667#15667

Comment: Blender will struggle with polycounts in millions. If you can, reduce the subdivision amounts. If you need to work with such subdivision amounts you need to get an app that will handle it, like Zbrush. Your pc is not the bottle-neck.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for the slowdown is due to how dense your model is. Generally it's a trade-off between quality and performance. in this instance you are using a multi-resolution modifier as well as a subdivision modifier. Both modifiers accomplish pretty similar tasks however in this case your subdivision modifier is subdividing an already subdivided surface adding significantly more vertices than what is needed in your model. This is why your are experiencing such a large amount of slowdown due to the amount of subdivisions that are in place.

I recommend picking either the the multi-resolution modifier or the subdivision modifier and sticking with that.